# How to prevent problems with `return` from block when using Ruby `yield`

Tags: ruby, yield

As every Ruby programmer eventually discovers, calling blocks or procs that contain `return` statements can be dangerous as this might exit your current context:

```
def some_method(&_block)
   puts 1
   yield
   # The following line will never be executed in this example
   # as the yield is actually a `yield-and-return`.
   puts 3
end

def test
  some_method do
    puts 2
    return
  end
end

test

# This prints "1\n2\n" instead of "1\n2\n3\n"
```

In cases you want to be absolutely sure some of your code runs *after* you called a block or proc, you can use a `begin ... ensure` construct. But since `ensure` is also called if there is an exception during yield, it requires a little more work.

I've created a [tiny module](https://gist.github.com/remofritzsche/8423f16efa2d7ca8943b2b5841ffa5ee) that deals with this problem in two different ways:

1. Using `safe_yield`, it is detected whether the yielded block or proc actually returns using the `return` keyword. If so, it raises an exception.

   ```
   unknown_block = proc do
     return
   end 

   ReturnSafeYield.safe_yield(unknown_block)
   # => Raises a UnexpectedReturnException exception
   ```
2. Using `call_then_yield`, you can call a block and then make sure that a second block is executed, even if the first block contains a `return` statement.

   ```
   unknown_block = proc do
     return
   end
   ReturnSafeYield.call_then_yield(unknown_block) do
     # => This line is called even though the above block contains a `return`.
   end
   ```

I'm considering to create a quick Gem out of this, or is there any built-in solution to prevent quick return from the nested block which I missed?

Comment: Just added a little example showing the problem. The basic issue only arises when you're not in control of the block / proc you're yielding (i.e. when writing a library).

Comment: This will break a default ruby behavior, bringing more pain, than profit. Imagine I am the consumer of the code that uses this trick. As I put `return` inside my block, I expect it to pass control immediately, and I would be damn surprised that some weird exception was raised.

Comment: Covering hunting pits with a hay only hides a trap, making code harder to debug. Ruby is not a language to protect people from shooting their legs, and this is the main advantage of it.

Comment: This is not a good idea, but it _is_ a good question.  Thank you for asking an interesting question.

Comment: Why would you pass (or even create) a proc containing a `return` statement in the first place?

Comment: @Stefan the question, AFAIU, is about how to protect _our_ code, that `yield`s, from the dumb consumer, who calls `return` in the block leading to _us_ losing the control. BTW, `return` from a block is a dangerous but effective stack unwind practice in some limited number of cases (e.g. in recursive block calls :)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the code you linked does not support block arguments, what after all makes it completely useless.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'd use `ensure` in that case, regardless of the cause. Regarding the limited use cases – this only works for block created within the method. You can't pass a `return` to a method from the outside, can you?

Comment: @Stefan I am not sure I understood the last sentence, could you please explore? One can [technically] pass a `return` to a method from the outside via the `block` having `return`. In such a case `yield` [technically] becomes yield-and-return :)

Comment: @mudasobwa really? `def foo; yield; end; foo { return }` results in a `LocalJumpError`

Comment: @Stefan: Yes: `def foo; yield; end; def main; foo { return }; end`. @mudasobwa: Exactly, the point of this approach is to protect our library code from possible programming mistakes out there. Good point with block arguments, will attempt to fix that.

Comment: Method `safe_yield` now supports block arguments. Thanks @mudasobwa for the hint.

Comment: Just to be clear: These methods are *not* meant for standard cases, but in very specific applications they might be useful. For instance, we're writing some kind of a transaction wrapping library that can be called with something like `Tx.t { ... }`. Inside such a block, a `return` is just wrong and would lead to unexpected behavior, so the `begin ... rescue` construct is an absolute necessity there. And if it gets a little more complicated, I tend to hide such non-business-logic complexity in external modules such as this one.

Comment: @Remo the blocks accept block as block argument (argh :) and the block _is not accessible_ via `args`. That said, you should add the block argument `self.safe_yield(block, *args, &cb)` to your methods as well.

Comment: @Remo I still think `ensure` is the right way here. Why would you want to `puts 3` in case of a `return` but not in case of an error / exception. Why should your code care about what's happening within yield?

Comment: @Stefan: Think of something very simple: `state = :running; yield; state = :success;`. In this example, your library code might be stuck in state `running` if the consumer is not careful. If you're just coding without thinking about the return, you wouldn't need an `ensure` for this case but could just write it as above, maybe wrap a `begin ... rescue` around it to set the state to `exception` or what not. And using `safe_yield`, you can do just that without having to worry about dangerous use cases by the consumer of your library.

Comment: Me, I believe that users should be totally allowed to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @Remo (1) If your code took a lambda rather than a block/proc, then `return` in the passed-in code would only return from the lambda.  (2) Have you considered posting this question on  http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I don't think there are legitimate use cases, considering that you have `try`/`catch` if you want to do crazy jumps through the stack.

Comment: If you really, really, **really** want code to run, use `ensure`. When you call `yield` you're briefly surrendering control to some other block of code and you need to be able to live with the consequences.

Comment: oooooo, this makes my skin crawl. We're OK if we get around `return`, but what if block also contains `launch_missiles(:now)`? Surely untrusted code cannot be allowed to pass a block or proc (e.g., raise an exception if `block_given?`), and we may need to carefully examine the arguments being passed before blindly executing the method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I totally get your point. I agree that if the "block author" wants to blow up the world, it should. But the point is a different one: It was an active decision to launch the missiles. It is however totally unknown to the "block author" what happens if `return` is used instead. We can't protect API users from every mistake, but we can protect it from some mistakes that would otherwise need detailed knowledge of an API's internal code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your valuable feedback. I get that there is quite some 'resistance', but we have a situation where we really need a proper solution for this. So I took the liberty of creating a Gem anyway (https://github.com/remofritzsche/return_safe_yield). I've stated in the readme that this is a contraversal Gem. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for the Gem or the readme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in solution to detect whether a block contains a `return` statement.

You can use [`RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-c-disasm) to disassemble the block passed in by the user, then search it for `throw 1`, which represents a `return` statement.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
def safe_yield(&block)
  if RubyVM::InstructionSequence.disasm(block) =~ /^\d+ throw +1$/
    raise LocalJumpError
  end

  block.call
end
```

Here's how you might incorporate it into your library:

```
def library_method(&block)
  safe_yield(&block)
  puts "library_method succeeded"
rescue LocalJumpError
  puts "library_method encountered illegal return but resumed execution"
end
```

And here's the user experience for a well-behaved and a misbehaving user:

```
def nice_user_method
  library_method { 1 + 1 }
end

nice_user_method
# library_method succeeded

def naughty_user_method
  library_method { return false if rand > 0.5 }
end

naughty_user_method
# library_method encountered illegal return but resumed execution
```

**Commentary:**

Using `raise LocalJumpError`/`rescue LocalJumpError` gets around the issues you encountered when using a blanket `ensure`.

I chose `LocalJumpError` because it seems relevant, and because (I think!) there is no possible Ruby code that would result in `LocalJumpError` being raised "naturally" in this context. If that turns out to be false, you can easily substitute your own new exception class.